# Rewrite binary executable to use GPU/be multithreaded?

Tags: multithreading, optimization, compiler-construction, gpu

Is there any tool that can rewrite a binary for me to use a GPU, SSE instructions,  or be multithreaded?     I have a program that is single-threaded and have a lot of spare cycles,  but I don't have the source.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic tools for this task because parallelizing code requires to understand it, except for trivial cases like loops.

There are tools that can operate at the source level to make more or less trivial parallelization but once the code is compiled you lose a lot of the semantical information.

You could try to parallelize it at a higher level by spawning **multiple processes**.

E.g. if this binary takes a parameter *n* and its execution time is linear with regards to *n* then spawning *p* processes could at best divide your running time by *p*.

Of course you should ensure this program does not do things that are not compatible with parallelization because you could really mess things up: imagine this program uses a file to store temporary data, running two instances would probably corrupt the file.

So before trying to run parallel instances cautiously determine the perimeter of the binary: files, databases, system resources (mutex, semaphores...).
If it's using files located in the same folder then you'll have to duplicate the binary in *p* folders too.

Comment: Thanks pragma -- I'm guessing there are loops in the code and that they consume most of the time,  hoping someone has written something to refactor these.

Comment: @OneSolitaryNoob: I wouldn't count on it. :) And even if you find some tools that promise this be really careful because fiddling with a binary is quite daring.

Comment: i looked quite a bit,  there is a field called "binary optimization",  but looks like it hasn't had much momentum recently.